# To store the array element at index inside a for loop or not

Tags: c#, for-loop, refactoring

Consider the following two for-loops in C#. Does either have any advantages/disadvantages over the other?

One without storing the element at index *i*.

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
    if(array[i].foo == 5) array[i].foo = array[i].bar + array[i].qux;

    // More usages of 'array[i]'
}
```

And one with storing the element at index *i* in a local variable

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
    var e = array[i];

    if(e.foo == 5) e.foo = e.bar + e.qux;

    // More usages of 'e'
}
```

The IDE I'm using converts foreach loops to for loops in the form of the latter and I want to learn the reasoning behind it if there is any

Comment: The reason it does that is to minimize the changes required to the code in your loop.

Comment: array[i].foo more longer operation than e.foo because array[i] have many operations inside

Comment: @juharr So the only reason is to protect user preference of readability and code familiarity?

Comment: @SarperS More likely because it's easier and safer if it makes as few changes as possible.

Comment: In a multithreading scenario it would make a huge difference. If you would do the calculations in a separate method which takes an array element as parameter and you would let it run in a separate thread for each element, this would lead to very different results. The first version would lead to a `IndexOutOfRangeException` because of closure, but the second version will work just fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, the second practice is more readable. it reduces code duplication and you do not need to declare `array[i]` in every calculation.

Your second question was about why your IDE converts `for-each` loops to `for` loops, basically `for-each` loops treats your object as enumerable which means its a collection of other objects and they implement IEnumerator interface, IEnumerator objects implement a design pattern in its self called Iterator pattern which allows you to iterate in the collection and get the next value of the collection.
Long story short `For` loops have better performance in arrays since they are using less calculation to retrieve the next value, but usually it is not something you should be worry about.

Comment: this explains why the ide keeps converting and its a cleaner answer too... lol

Comment: Just for clarification, the IDE does not convert the foreach loops to for loops, on the contrary it advises me to use foreach loops where applicable. It just prefers the latter form if I tell it to convert. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It's worth noting that `foreach` loops aren't going to be slower for all types of collections. A numeric `for` loop is certainly faster for an Array, but not for, say, a List, where lookups by index aren't necessarily constant-time.

Comment: @MattRollins you are right, i have added "in arrays" to my answer for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

It is JUST refactoring. There is no speed boost, there's no secret technique being used, its just refactoring. It just makes your job easier when you need to edit the code so instead of writing out array[i].this and array[i].that and array[i].otherstuff you do e.this e.that e.otherstuff. quicker to type and a bit easier to read...

Comment: They are not the same. In the first version, the array must be accessed over and over again, while it's only used once in the second version

Comment: please do a ctrl+f on same and see where i mentioned it

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, surely that's just perception - in reality the compiler will optimise both versions to the same code?

Comment: i say so too spod it's just changed from array[i] to just calling e... nothing crazy like you said bud.. simple refactoring